# Access multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
 array(10) {
  ["table_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["chart_type"]=>
  string(5) "Table"
  ["chart_name"]=>
  string(9) "Veterans "
  ["dashboard_name"]=>
  string(7) "Default"
  ["data_option"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["limit_value"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["view_status"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["view_priority"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["chart_data"]=>
  array(72) {
    [0]=>
    array(11) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "Rank"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "Branch"
      [2]=>
      string(12) "Level 3 Name"
      [3]=>
      string(12) "Level 4 Name"
      [4]=>
      string(23) "Logged Premia Score MTD"
      [5]=>
      string(26) "Converted Premia Score MTD"
      [6]=>
      string(21) "Persistancy Score MTD"
      [7]=>
      string(23) "Logged Premia Score YTD"
      [8]=>
      string(26) "Converted Premia Score YTD"
      [9]=>
      string(21) "Persistancy Score YTD"
      [10]=>
      string(5) "Score"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(11) {
      [0]=>
      float(1)
      [1]=>
      string(22) " GWALIOR DIRECTSegment"
      [2]=>
      string(29) "G00563 - GOVIND SINGH KUSHWAH"
      [3]=>
      string(21) "S03643 - Shishir Jain"
      [4]=>
      float(1)
      [5]=>
      float(1)
      [6]=>
      float(1)
      [7]=>
      float(0.9994)
      [8]=>
      float(1)
      [9]=>
      float(1)
      [10]=>
      float(9.89901)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(11) {
      [0]=>
      float(2)
      [1]=>
      string(26) " KURUKSHETRA DIRECTSegment"
      [2]=>
      string(23) "A02311 - Amarjeet Singh"
      [3]=>
      string(21) "S00927 - Sachin Kumar"
      [4]=>
      float(1)
      [5]=>
      float(1)
      [6]=>
      float(1)
      [7]=>
      float(0.953)
      [8]=>
      float(1)
      [9]=>
      float(1)
      [10]=>
      float(9.82245)
    }

  }
  ["color_scheme_name"]=>
  string(7) "Default"
}
```

How do i display the `chart_data` in php

```
      $arr=json_decode($row[0],TRUE);

         var_dump($arr);

         foreach($arr as $row)
{
       foreach($row['chart_data'] as $k)
       {
             echo $k['Rank'];
             echo $k['Branch'];
       }
}
```

EDIT:

```
for ($x=0; $x<=count
($arr['chart_data']); $x++) {

foreach($arr['chart_data'][$x] as $key=>$val)
{


  echo $val;
}
}
```

Comment: format the array please.

Comment: `?><pre><?php var_dump($arr); ?></pre><?php`

Comment: That's not readable it doesn't even indent.

Comment: Have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is solution.

```
$arr = json_decode($row[0],TRUE);

foreach($row['chart_data'] as $chart_data)
{
    foreach($chart_data[0] as $k)
    {
        echo $k['Rank'];
        echo $k['Branch'];
    }
}
```

**Update** :

**Rank**, **Branch** is values. Your array is bad format.

```
$arr = json_decode($row[0],TRUE);

foreach($row['chart_data'] as $chart_data)
{
    foreach($chart_data[0] as $k)
    {
        echo $k[0];
        echo $k[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having 2 foreach calls.

The first one passes all keys of the outer array, amongst which `chart_data`.

The second one looks at the children of the outer array, and looks for `chart_data` in each child. But is obviously not finding any.

Change your code to this:

```
$arr=json_decode($row[0],TRUE);
foreach($arr['chart_data'] as $k){
    echo $k['Rank'];
    echo $k['Branch'];
}
```

**edit:**

I see. (Thanks for indenting your array) Your problem is off course that `$arr['rank']`and `$arr['branch']` don't exist. They are mere strings inside `$k[0]` and `$k[1]` and themselves don't contain any other data.

**What would you have like to see outputted?**